# How to get values from a schema to be available as a const

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I know how this can be done in php, but in javascript i don't know that much, but i will find the best possible way to explain myself.
let say i have a schema called setting schema where i do save some api keys and it have this result

```
{
    "_id": "5d7f77d620cf10054ded50bb",
    "dimension": 166,
    "stripe": "Axd3232wed22342214r2",
    "paystack": "fiasfd321r23r3vb.dfaedw1",
}
```

so i design a setting.js where i called out all this value's using the module.export

```
const express = require('express');

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Settings = require('../../models/Settings');

module.exports = {
     dimension : function getDimension() {
          return Settings.find({_id : "5d7f77d620cf10054ded50bb"},{dimension:1}, (err, res) => {
            if(err) throw new Error(err.message, null);
             const holder = res[0].dimension; 
            return holder;
          });
        },

    stripe: function getStripe() {
          return Settings.find({_id : "5d7f77d620cf10054ded50bb"},{stripe:1}, (err, res) => {
            if(err) throw new Error(err.message, null);
             const stripe = res[0].stripe; 
            return stripe;
          });
        },

    paystack: function getPaystack() {
          return Settings.find({_id : "5d7f77d620cf10054ded50bb"},{paystack:1}, (err, res) => {
            if(err) throw new Error(err.message, null);
             const paystack = res[0].paystack; 
            return paystack;
          });
        },
}
```

so all i want is if i import this setting.js and i also import

```
   const settings = require(./settings)
   const dimension = settings.dimension
```

if i console.log dimension all i get is `[Function: getDimension]` 
instead of
 `166` 
all i want is i want this value to be available globally within my application

Comment: my question is different

Comment: You're attempting to `return` the result of an asynchronous method. That won't work. You need to either use a callback to propagate the result or `Promises` or `async`/`await`. Check out the duplicate.

Comment: @NikKyriakides is 100% right here

Comment: Then help me do it, am not too familiar with asynchronous programming